# Как перебрать в цикле весь массив [0,1,2,3,4] начиная с третьего элемента: 2,3,4,0,1?

Tags: javascript

Как перебрать в цикле весь массив `[0,1,2,3,4]` начиная с третьего элемента: `2,3,4,0,1`?

Comment: @KiiDii это обыденная невнимателность прочтения "чего нужно" =) такое бывает

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Предотвратить выход за пределы массива с зацикливанием легко сделать при помощи нахождения остатка от деления**

При проведении обычной итерации берем индекс и прибавляем к нему необходимое смещение.

Пока индекс меньше длины массива остаток от деления этого числа на длину будет равен исходному числу.
А когда он станет больше или равен длине, мы получим смещения от начала:

`0 + 2 = 2`  `->`   `2 % 5 = 2`

`1 + 2 = 3`  `->`   `3 % 5 = 3`

`2 + 2 = 4`  `->`   `4 % 5 = 4`

`3 + 2 = 5`  `->`   `5 % 5 = 0`

`4 + 2 = 6`  `->`   `6 % 5 = 1`

---

При помощи цикла:

```js
let arr = [0,1,2,3,4], 
    start = 2;
    
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  let index = (i + start) % arr.length;
  console.log(arr[index]);
}
```

---

Через `forEach`

```js
let arr = ['яблоко','груша','ананас','мандарин','арбуз'], start = 2;
arr.forEach((e,i) => console.log(arr[(i+start)%arr.length]))
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95815/discussion-on-answer-by-stranger-in-the-q-------0-1).

Answer (score 7):

```js
let arr = [0,1,2,3,4], start = 2;

var i = start;

do{
  if (i == arr.length) i = 0;
  console.log(arr[i]);
  i++;
}
while (i != start)
```

Comment: да я уже заметил, но я не стал бы рекомендовать данный код новичку. В лучшем случае - он просто скопирует его к себе и оно будет работать у него, пока он даже не понимает что происходит, в худшем случае - код у него и вовсе работать не будет как надо.

Comment: @KiiDii т е это действие будет новичку понятнее ?? arr[(i+start)%arr.length] )) Я ж показал типичный `do{} while()`

Comment: имеет право на жизнь, но не понимаю что сложного в одной арифметической операции, это даже не комплексные числа или кватернионы (я про остаток от деления)

Comment: @Виталий, тот ответ мне был более понятен. Конечно это может быть связано с тем, что do {} while(), в моей практике появляется крайне редко, однако в ваш ответ мне пришлось вчитываться, чтобы его понять, тогда, как ответ, StrangerintheQ на данный момент расписан так, как мне в своё время никто и никогда не разжевывал.

Answer (score 4):

```js
// Это наши входные данные, именно с этим массивом мы хотим работать
let array = [0,1,2,3,4];

// Не стоит изменять входные данные, т.к. скорее всего вам с ними ещё работать в будущем, поэтому переложим их в новый массив
// Метод slice (БЕЗ АРГУМЕНТОВ), необходим для того, чтобы создать независимую копию массива, а не ссылаться на входные данные
let enumArray = array.slice();

// Метод удалит 2 элемента начиная с индекса 0.
// И сохранит удалённые элементы в новый массив.
const removed = enumArray.splice(0, 2);

// Возвращаем удалённые элементы в конец массива. 
// Длинна массива в нашем случае будет служить индексом с которого нужно добавить обратно в массив все удаленные элементы
enumArray.splice(enumArray.length, 0, ...removed);

enumArray.forEach((item) => {
  console.info(item);
});
```

- Подробней о методе splice почитайте пожалуйста [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
- Подробней про независимые копии массивов почитайте пожалуйста [здесь](https://noteskeeper.ru/1/)